# How to recrod our screen of android emulator operations

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am automating my android app through Appium in Emulator. During the test case run, i want to capture all operations performed in the emulator into a video. How can i do this? 
As i want to deal with programmatically, are there any APIs supported to do this?
Is there any methods to do this using Java?

I heard that we can record for Android real devices(**adb shell screenrecorder**), but not for Emulator.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks,
Uday

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the emulator itself as a windows application and hence you could record it like any other windows app. For a more platform independent option, there are a few [java libraries](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.htmlhttp://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.html?m=1) with api.

Comment: Actually i see both methods have some drawback. The first method "MonteScreenRecorder" method have some unnecessary methods, which they would have handled internally. The other method specified in comments is "Microsoft Expression Encoder 4" which is easy, but it needs to install on a machine(rather than just referencing like including jar files). Both above methods lack recording a specific window(in my case it is emulator window). Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: is there a way to improve the quality of the video in Monte Screen Recroder? What parameters has to be changed for better quality?